# bash show git branch as dirty all the time

Tags: git, bash, git-branch

I am using a bash script that I found online somewhere, and it is everywhere, to display current git branch.

```
function parse_git_dirty {
  [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" ]] && echo "*"
}
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/[\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/"
}

export PS1='\w\[\033[1;37m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[0m\]$ '
```

This worked fine on my Mac. But I recently got a new Mac and passed all my data in through my backup. However on my new machine the branch state seems always dirty.

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
~/Desktop/Work/relearning_rails[master*]$
```

This is the result of a git status. I can't figure this out for the life of me. Do I have to change something in this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string it's looking for is wrong.  `parse_git_dirty` should look like this:

```
function parse_git_dirty {
  [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "nothing to commit, working directory clean" ]] && echo "*"
}
```

A better implementation might be something like:

```
function parse_git_dirty {
  [[ -n "$(git status -s 2> /dev/null)" ]] && echo "*"
}
```

This version would rely on whether any data was returned, rather than examining the data.

You may want to consider looking at [`git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) though.  It's a much more complete prompt.  Directions on how to use it are in the script itself.

Comment: It seems as if with every git update they change the "nothing to commit, working directory clean" back and forth. I suffer from the same but were too lazy so far to strive for a better solution than just adjusting the string every time. Thanks for pointing out a better solution :)

Comment: this code you have in your answer does what I want, and is my current solution but I will take a look at git-prompt.sh too. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

The [contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c26f70ceb3960603a78010c87f8ad11820ab6561/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L475-L484) just got more robust for git 2.6.4 or 2.7 (Dec. 2015):

```
git diff --no-ext-diff --quiet || w="*"
git diff --no-ext-diff --cached --quiet || i="+"
if [ -z "$short_sha" ] && [ -z "$i" ]; then
    i="#"
fi
```

See [commit c26f70c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c26f70ceb3960603a78010c87f8ad11820ab6561), [commit 0af9f7e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0af9f7ecb8648ab1c6a090913e3df4a39f7c6754), [commit a30d11e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a30d11ebdf78cfd664554090ce31673b01c8fd3b) (21 Nov 2015) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 80c17ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80c17cac368c8acf47d5b79b4f5e40d4018efa42), 04 Dec 2015)</sup>

> ### bash prompt: indicate dirty index even on orphan branches
>
> `__git_ps1()` doesn't indicate dirty index while on an orphan branch.
>
> To check the dirtiness of the index, `__git_ps1()` runs '`git diff-index --cached ... HEAD`', which doesn't work on an orphan branch, because `HEAD` doesn't point to a valid commit.
>
> Run '`git diff ... --cached`' instead, as it does the right thing both on valid and invalid `HEAD`, i.e. compares the index to the existing HEAD in the former case and to the empty tree in the latter.
>   This fixes the two failing tests added in the first commit of this series.
>
> The dirtiness of the worktree is already checked with '`git diff`' and
>   is displayed correctly even on an orphan branch.